# "Попасть впросак"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Говорят "попасть впросак". А что такое вообще этот "просак"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Попасть впросак** значит попасть в затруднительное, неловкое или смешное положение. Это собственно русское выражение. Истоки его - в быту старых русских прядильщиков, канатных мастеров. Оно образовалось из свободного сочетания **попасть в просак**. Просак - канатный, веревочный стан, на котором в старину сучили веревки. Он представлял собой сложную сеть веревок, тянувшихся от прядильного колеса до саней, где они скручивались. Стан располагался на улице и занимал значительное пространство. Для прядильщика попасть в такой стан одеждой или бородой означало лишиться и того и другого, а порой и жизни. С утратой реалии забылось прямое значение оборота и укрепилось переносное. В XVIII в. сочетаемость слова *просак* была более свободна - *встречались обороты типа будешь в просаке, попался в преизрядный просак, ввели меня в такой просак* и т.п. (Историко-этимологический словарь "Русская фразеология" Бириха и др.)

Answer (score 4):

Немного сомневаюсь, что речь идёт именно о том просаке, который у прядильщиков. Замысловато как-то...

Но просаком называлось ещё и приспособление (ременное или веревочное), с помощью которого стереноживали лошадь. Для ковки или оскопления. Тут уж никаких замысловатых пояснений о бороде или одежде не требуется. Коли попал - так попал.

Answer (score -2):

Кто-нибудь из современных людей может назвать, как называется хоть какой-нибудь станок у ткачей? Или у крутильщиков канатов, веревок? Или хотя-бы какой-нибудь термин, применяемый в данном производстве? Почему же современные люди не знают, при развитии информационных технологий, а жители в старину были так осведомлены о тонкостях производства веревок в Новгороде? Да и откуда знали жители, что в Новгороде есть какие-то станки для изготовления веревок и канатов? Тогда в каждом доме с помощью веретена и прялки вили нити, почти в каждом доме имелся ткацкий станок для изготовления домотканной ткани, и почти каждый ребенок мог свить веревочку нужных параметров.. Отсюта и выражения - вить веревки, сучить, но не "просачить"... Сабанеев, создавая свою книгу, привел рисунок СУЧИЛЬНОГО приспособления для сучения лески из конского волоса, но не ПРОСАЧНОГО! Скорее всего, слово "просак" означало именно то, что Михалков высказал в фильме "Жмурки", а Даль, ища "приличное" происхождение популярного выражения "Попасть впросак", приплел суда новгородских вильщиков канатов.. Кстати, это выражение касалось, скорее всего, обеих полов, и подобное выражение было у казаков - "попасть в просак" - это значило больно удариться упомянутым местом, скажем, о край седла и оставить себе незабываемые впечатления. При этом положение оказывалось крайне затруднительным неудобным и досадным, поскольку случалось при скачке и даже остановиться и слезть с коня было нельзя, только терпеть..

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос? Пока я вижу только многословную критику.